# Boostrap tab-pane fill 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

On an application based on the sb admin 2 boostrap template
https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/

In one of the pages I have some bootstrap tabs. One of the tabs contains a grid and I want to make only that tab fill the height of the remaining of the page.
I tried using height 100% but that would mean placing it on tab-content and is not really what I want for the rest of the tabs.(the rest of the tabs the content can have greater height and support the browser toolbar)

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 0):

if you use
min-height: 100vW;
this should work for your table and allow the other ones to be larger

Comment: Set min-height to what control?